# How can I fix my collisions?

Tags: python, pygame

Here is my collision code.

```
def collide_with_walls(self, dir):
            if dir == 'x':
                hits = pg.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.game.walls, False)
                if hits:
                    if self.vel.x > 0:
                        self.pos.x = hits[0].rect.left - self.rect.width 
                    if self.vel.x < 0:
                        self.pos.x = hits[0].rect.right
                    self.vel.x = 0
                    self.rect.x = self.pos.x
            if dir == 'y':
                hits = pg.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.game.walls, False)
                if hits:
                    if self.vel.y > 0:
                        self.pos.y = hits[0].rect.top
                    if self.vel.y < 0:
                        self.pos.y = hits[0].rect.bottom
                    self.vel.y = 0
                    self.rect.y = self.pos.y
```

Everything works well, except it allows my player sprite to partially walk inside and outside of the wall depending on the side I enter from.

[image: Can walk partially inside wall]
[image: Can't walk any further]

Image 1: Can walk partially into wall. 
Image 2: Can't walk any further.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably move your character's sprite a little to the right, just like you did with the positive x direction:

```
if self.vel.x < 0:
    self.pos.x = hits[0].rect.right + self.rect.width
```

You can even change offset only to the half of the character sprite if you want to be able to move close to the walls:

```
if self.vel.x > 0:
    self.pos.x = hits[0].rect.left - self.rect.width//2 
if self.vel.x < 0:
    self.pos.x = hits[0].rect.right + self.rect.width//2
```

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it, it seems that there is a misalignment between the positioning of the sprite hit box and the sprite image.

It is however a bit more difficult to pinpoint the exact reason why that is happening without knowing the internals of the sprite object and the spritecollision function.

Try offsetting your calculations by half a rectangle in either direction to see if it helps.